# Method of variation of parameters for the following DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=e^{-x}\sin(e^{-x})+\cos(e^{-x})$$
solved the CF part facing issue with PI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y''-y=0$ has solutuons
$y_1=e^x, y_2=e^{-x}, W(x)=-2$
Solution of $$Y"(x)-Y(x)=e^{-x}\sin e^{-x}+\cos e^{-x}=f(x)~~~(1)$$
Can be written as $$Y(x)=C_1(x) y_1(x)+ C_2(x) y_2(x),~~~~(2)$$ where
$$C_1(x)=-\int \frac{y_2 f(x)}{W} dx+D_1, ~~~C_2=\int \frac{y_1 f(x)}{W} dx+D_2$$
So $$C_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int -e^{-x}[e^{-x}\sin e^{-x}+\cos e^{-x}] dx$$
$$C_1(x)=\frac{1}{2} \int (t\sin t+ \cos t) dt=-t \cos t+2\sin t=-e^{-x}\cos e^{-x}+2 \sin e^{-x}.$$
$$C_2(x)=\frac{-1}{2}\int \sin e^{-x}+e^{x} \sin e^{-x} dx=\frac{-1}{2}e^{x}\cos e^{-x}.$$
Insewrting them in (2), we get the complete solutions with $D_1,D_2$ as undetermined constants.

Comment: thanks for the help that integration was very tricky